# [Angular][Store] Problem with injecting a service into another service

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, store, ngrx

I've got a following problem. I've created a service - let's call it CopyService. I'm injecting Store into it.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CopyService {  
  constructor(
    private copyStore: Store<fromCopyStore.CopyState>,
  ) {
    //something going on with the store
  } 

}
```

Further on, I'm injecting CopyService into MenuService

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MenuService {

  constructor(private copyService: CopyService) { 
    // something going on with the copyService
  }
  
 }
```

Lastly, MenuService is being injected into a Component:

```js
export class Component implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(
    private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
    private menuService: MenuService,    
  ) {
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
      // something going on with the menuService
  }
}
```

Apologies for only a draft of the actual code, but I'm not sure how much of it I can actually show.
The problem is anyways, that I get a StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Component -> Store] No provider for Store!

I can seem to get down to the source of the problem. The CopyService is of course listed in the providers section of the MainModule of my application.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [    
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {})       
  ],
  providers: [CopyService],
  entryComponents: [
    //entry components
  ],
  declarations: [
    //declarations
  ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

I'm digging into the Angular's Dependency Injection, but so far there's been no route that would point me into the right direction with this problem.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should import the store in your module.

See https://ngrx.io/guide/store#tutorial

Comment: hi, I've edited the post - the Store is already imported in my module

Comment: If you have a reproduction I'm happy to take a look